# how to make a null query selecting all the items

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I really like the `query` method. What is the `null` query that select all the items? I have tried `df.query("True")`, but it doesn't work.

The only thing I have found to work is `df.query("index == 0 | index != 0")`.

Why "True" is not working, it is a predicate.

Answer (score 1):

For me works:

```
df.query("index")
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6]},
                   index=[-1,4,5])

print (df)
    A  B
-1  1  4
 4  2  5
 5  3  6

a = df.query("index")
print (a)
    A  B
-1  1  4
 4  2  5
 5  3  6
```

If index values are not negative, use:

```
a = df.query("index > -1")
print (a)
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

EDIT by comment:

I am not `query` expert, but if use `True` only, it search values in index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6]}, 
                    index=[True,0,'d'])

print (df)
      A  B
True  1  4
0     2  5
d     3  6

a = df.query("True")
print (a)
A    1
B    4
Name: True, dtype: int64

b = df.query('0')
print (b)
A    2
B    5
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Another crazy index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6]}, 
                    index=[True,True,True])

print (df)
      A  B
True  1  4
True  2  5
True  3  6

a = df.query("True")
print (a)
      A  B
True  1  4
True  2  5
True  3  6
```

Comment: seems to me a quick and dirty solution, I would like to specify a predicate. "index" wouble be "index != False". In fact if I set all the index of `df` to be equal to `0` I get strange result.

Comment: You should have provided an example.